# apply many expressions to one row of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, expression, eval, rules

I have input data `X` in the form of a single row of a matrix that is updated several times per second

```
# fake data  
set.seed(123)
X <- matrix(rnorm(1),ncol = 10,nrow = 1)
```

I have a model in the form of rules, many rules, about a thousand.
In order not to copy my model, I will create a fake.

Rules in the model **can be** of different sizes

```
fake_rules_model <- function(n=1000, ncolX){
idx <- function() sample(1:ncolX,n,replace = T)
val <- function() round(rnorm(n),2)
op <- function() sample(c("<=",">="),n,replace = T)
rules <- paste0("X[,",idx(),"]",op(),val()," & ","X[,",idx(),"]",op(),val())
return(rules)}


model <- fake_rules_model(ncolX = ncol(X))
```

I have a function that executes a model `model_execute`

```
model_execute <- function(model){
  res <- rep(F,length(model))
    for(i in 1:length(model))    res[i] <-  eval(str2lang( model[i] ))
return(res)  
}




model_execute(model = model)
   [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  [14] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [27] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  [40]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

but it's too slow for me

**Question:** How to speed up the `model_execute` function

Comment: Do the rules have to be created dynamically, or are they fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to construct matrices and compare them:

```
f <- function(model){
  
  m <- do.call(
    rbind,
    stringr::str_match_all(
      model,
      "(\\[,([0-9]+)\\](<=|>=)(-?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*))+"
    )
  )
  m <- m[,3:5]
  
  X_m <- matrix(X[,as.integer(m[,1])], ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  val_m <- matrix(as.numeric(m[,3]), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  op_m <- matrix(m[,2], ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

  modify <- which(op_m == ">=")
  X_m[modify] <- -1 * X_m[modify] 
  val_m[modify] <- -1 * val_m[modify]
  apply(X_m <= val_m, 1, all)
}

> identical(f(model), model_execute(model))
[1] TRUE

> rbenchmark::benchmark(
+   model_execute = model_execute(model),
+   f = f(model)
+ )
           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2             f          100    0.33    1.000      0.33        0         NA        NA
1 model_execute          100    4.27   12.939      4.25        0         NA        NA
```

**edit**

you can generalize, but it will be slower than first variant:

```
ff <- function(model){
  
  lgl <- lapply(
    stringr::str_match_all(
      model, 
      "\\[,([0-9]+)\\](<=|>=)(-?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)"
    ),
    function(x){
      
      l_val <- X[,as.integer(x[,2])]
      s <- x[,3]
      r_val <- as.numeric(x[,4])

      modify <- which(s == ">=")
      l_val[modify] <- -l_val[modify]
      r_val[modify] <- -r_val[modify]
      all(l_val <=r_val)
    }
  )
  
  unlist(lgl)
}

           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2            ff          100    0.67    1.000      0.67     0.00         NA        NA
1 model_execute          100    4.34    6.478      4.32     0.02         NA        NA
```